# Rails5: fixtures containing json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, fixtures

I need to create a fixture for model Request with following fields:
body -> JSON
created_at - datetime
updated_at - datetime
remote_ip - i.e. 127.0.0.01
status - i.e. 1

I've tried:

```
request1:
  body: {"title": "test", "Action": "test_action"}
  created_at: 2018-06-13 21:15:51
  updated_at: 2018-06-13 21:15:51
  remote_ip: 127.0.0.1
  status: 1
```

but as a result i do not get o JSON inside body column in db but

```
---
title: test
Action: test action
```

What should i do to get full JSON in body field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest solution i've found is to treat json as a string:

```
body: '{"title": "test", "Action": "test_action"}'
```

It works, but i am not not sure if it is the best solution....